# ¿En que casos consideran necesario hacer cambios de estilo en en el JavaScript en lugar de utilizar el CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, style

Estuve leyendo un poco y leí algunos comentarios diciendo que muchas veces es mejor hacer cambios de estilo en el JS en lugar de CSS, y me gustaría tener algunos ejemplos, para optimizar mis códigos

Comment: Cambios de estilos, te refieres a dinámicamente? Clicar por ejemplo un botón y que un cuadrado se ponga rojo? (es solo un ejemplo)

Comment: por concepto de rapidez y de forma, todo cambio debería ser por css, cuando no puedes hacerlo por css alli es cuando debes usar JS.   y como nota, todo código bien optimizado será muy rígido, por consigiente no sera facil de modificar, en lugar de buscar optimizar busca la neutralidad en tu código

Comment: Cuando se necesita cambiar el estilo actual usando eventos: scroll, click, entonces si

Answer (score 0):

> Estuve leyendo un poco y leí algunos comentarios diciendo que muchas veces es mejor hacer cambios de estilo en el JS en lugar de CSS, y me gustaría tener algunos ejemplos, para optimizar mis códigos

**TL/DR** si quieres optimizar tu código, la idea es que sea ordenado, limpio y consistente. Todos los estilos debieran estar en el CSS. Si quieres optimizar tu proceso de desarrollo, entonces lo anterior se torna impráctico. El 90% del tiempo estarás ensayando con estilos un poco en modalidad prueba y error y de verdad no vas a recompilar o re-minificar el CSS cada vez.

---

La respuesta larga es que todo depende del caso de uso. Pensemos en un ejemplo burdo. Tienes un botón y quieres que al pasar el mouse por encima el texto cambie de color, volviendo a su color normal cuando el mouse sale de encima. Se puede hacer con JS

```js
const boton=document.querySelector('#boton');
boton.addEventListener('mouseover',(e)=>{
  boton.style.backgroundColor='#58B';
})
boton.addEventListener('mouseout',(e)=>{
  boton.style.backgroundColor='#369';
})
```

```css
.btn {
font-size:14px;
padding:2px 4px;
 border-radius:4px;
 background:#369;
 color:white;
}
```

```html
<button id="boton" class="btn">Click me</button>
```

Pero es un caso de uso que se puede resolver usando sólo CSS con el seudoselector `:hover`

```css
.btn {
font-size:14px;
padding:2px 4px;
 border-radius:4px;
 background:#369;
 color:white;
}

.btn:hover {
 background:#58B;
}
```

```html
<button id="boton" class="btn">Click me</button>
```

Ahora, si bien podrías estructurar toda tu aplicación para usar más o menos las mismas clases para todo lo que sea o se comporte como botón, es posible que sea un trabajo extra andar escribiendo CSS para cada cosa que pueda cambiar cuando pases el mouse sobre ella. En otras palabras, puede ser mucho trabajo preocuparte de actualizar y compilar tu CSS (o al menos minificarlo) cada vez que le añades el estilo a cualquier clase que pueda necesitar `:hover`.

Pensemos en un caso de uso menos trivial. Ahora tú quieres que al hacer click el botón se deshabilite para evitar envíos duplicados. Vamos a hacerlo añadiendo el estilo

```
  pointer-events: none
```

```js
const boton = document.querySelector('#boton');

boton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  boton.style.pointerEvents = "none";
  boton.style.background = "gray";
  document.querySelector('#aviso').classList.toggle('hidden');
})
```

```css
.btn {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #369;
  color: white;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #58B;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="boton" class="btn">Click me</button>
<div id="aviso" class="hidden">Enviando...</div>
```

Cuál sería la manera "CSS" de hacer lo mismo? Crear una clase ".disabled" en el CSS que estableciera el color y comportamiento del botón, y dejar que el JS simplemente añadiera o quitara la clase. De nuevo, esto es perfectamente manejable, pero si tienes otros controles (otros bones, selects, checkboxes) y cada uno puede tener comportamientos distintos según tu UX/UI, es tedioso tener todo eso en el CSS, máxime si a veces se trata de comportamientos que se usan en un solo lugar.

Para poner sobre la mesa una tercera alternativa, te comento que hoy en día hay frameworks de CSS funcionales como [Tailwind](https://v1.tailwindcss.com/components/buttons) que te permiten poner esos comportamientos directo en el HTML.

```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.1.2/tailwind.min.css">
<button class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
  Button
</button>
```

Fíjate que los estilos del botón definen el hover de antemano:

```
 class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700"
```

...y si quieres hacer un cambio rápido en tu código sin recompilar el CSS, puedes hacerlo directo en el tag del elemento.

Entonces, ¿Cuándo tiene sentido cambiar los estilos via JS? Bueno, ya vimos un ejemplo en donde necesitas javascript para reaccionar a un click. Eso no lo puedes simplemente resolver con CSS. Hagamos el mismo ejemplo de deshabilitar un botón luego de un click, con Tailwind

```js
const boton = document.querySelector('#boton');

boton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  boton.classList.add('pointer-events-none');
  boton.classList.remove('bg-blue-500');
  boton.classList.add('bg-gray-300');
  document.querySelector('#aviso').classList.toggle('hidden');
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.1.2/tailwind.min.css">
<button id="boton" class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
  Button
</button>
<div id="aviso" class="hidden">Enviando...</div>
```

En el fondo, me apoyé en el css y más en Tailwind para cambiar el aspecto y el comportamiento del botón esta vez tocando clases y no estilos, pero necesité usar JS para hacer este cambio. Ese es sólo un ejemplo sencillo en donde esa manipulación directa no puede resolverse con CSS. Y si no estuviera ocupando Tailwind, lo haría simplemente con estilos porque, de nuevo, no voy a crear una clase para cada comportamiento particular asociado a una acción del usuario.

Comment: pareciera q a tailwind le faltan estilos para elementos diabled. ese ejemplo lo armaría en el JS:  `boton.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');` ;  en el CSS: `#aviso{display: none} button[disabled]{ background: gray}button[disabled]~#aviso {display: block}`. ( en realidad plantearía el asunto al encargado de UI/UX para resolver casos particulares )

Comment: Nooo en ningún caso. Parte de la base que Tailwind tenga todo. Y si no tiene, le añades tu CSS. Asume que todo lo básico ya existe. El hecho que mi ejemplo sea malo no condiciona la conclusión de fondo. El atributo disabled es natural en un botón, pero tu caso de uso puede ser infinitamente completo. Si un checkbox puede tener status `checked` `unchecked` y `undefined` tú puedes querer ponerle el estado `medianamente tibio cargado hacia el poniente`. Ahí viene la decisión no trivial de manipular esas variantes editando el css una y otra vez

Comment: o la desición no trivial de manipular esas variantes editando el javascript una y otra vez.

Comment: Ya, pero el JS puedes modificarlo "salpicando" distintas partes del código. No generas un build para modificar ese comportamiento. Pero la hoja de estilos no la puedes modificar sin un build a menos que sea muy simple y no venga de un SCSS. El equivalente sería meter etiquetas `<style>` en medio del código. En ese sentido la idea de "pequeños cambios en caliente" es más manejable en JS que en CSS. De todas maneras, sólo estoy respondiendo a la pregunta del usuario. "En qué casos es necesario..." con algunos escenarios que se me ocurren, pero no como buena práctica